# Android 5 Lollipop shadow direction or y offset

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, shadows

Is there a possibility to change the shadow direction of Y offset?

Right now I have the following layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

that reproduces the result on the left, but I like to achieve the effect on the right image
[image]

Can anyone point me directions how to do that?

Comment: No, you can't change the light position. It's fixed across all apps to provide a visually consistent lighting model. Have you considered rearranging your layers so that the top-most layer has the lowest elevation, like in the image on the right?

Comment: Yes but then there isn't shadow displayed beneath the views

Answer (score 1):

The [`setOutlineProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOutlineProvider(android.view.ViewOutlineProvider)) method on `View` added in API 21 may be of use. From the documentation:

> Sets the [`ViewOutlineProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) of the view, which generates the Outline that defines the shape of the shadow it casts, and enables outline clipping.

It allows customized shape for sure, but I'm not 100% certain that shadow direction can be altered.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that you can not set the X and Y offset for the shadows so I came up with a nice looking solution that gives the desired effect, it consists of a layerlist but the first layer will be a gradient to give a nice looking shadow effect like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:gravity="top" >

    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <size
            android:height="15dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </shape>



</item>
<item
    android:top="15dp">

    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    </shape>



</item>
</layer-list>
```

the top value of the second layer and the shape height of the first layer need to be the same but you can modify their values to achieve the desired elevation then all you have to do is set this as the background of the view to which you want to apply the elevation. Can also be used as an elevation alternative for pre-lolipop devices.

Also make sure to add top_padding equivalent to the height size indicated in the xml to the view to which you apply this as background.

NOTE : this will only look nice if your view takes the entire screen width since no shadow is applied to the sides.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to create a top shadow was to modify some of the source of the Android compatibility v7 `CardView` project. This project brings the CardView class to older Android versions and thus also includes the elevation shadow. The resulting shadow is very close to a "real" elevation shadow.

The important class from the `CardView` project is `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`.

I call it like this:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float elevation = 2;
xlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundRectDrawableWithShadow(
        getResources(), Color.BLACK, 0, 
        elevation*density, ((elevation +1 )*density) + 1
));
```

You'll need the following in `res/values/values.xml`

```
<color name="cardview_shadow_end_color">#03000000</color>
<color name="cardview_shadow_start_color">#47000000</color>
<dimen name="cardview_compat_inset_shadow">1dp</dimen>
```

Here the modified class `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package xxx;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import xxx.R;

/**
 * A rounded rectangle drawable which also includes a shadow around.
 */
public class RoundRectDrawableWithShadow extends Drawable {
    // used to calculate content padding
    final static double COS_45 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45));

    final static float SHADOW_MULTIPLIER = 1.5f;

    final int mInsetShadow; // extra shadow to avoid gaps between card and shadow

    /*
    * This helper is set by CardView implementations.
    * <p>
    * Prior to API 17, canvas.drawRoundRect is expensive; which is why we need this interface
    * to draw efficient rounded rectangles before 17.
    * */
    static RoundRectHelper sRoundRectHelper;

    Paint mPaint;

    Paint mCornerShadowPaint;

    Paint mEdgeShadowPaint;

    final RectF mCardBounds;

    float mCornerRadius;

    Path mCornerShadowPath;

    // updated value with inset
    float mMaxShadowSize;

    // actual value set by developer
    float mRawMaxShadowSize;

    // multiplied value to account for shadow offset
    float mShadowSize;

    // actual value set by developer
    float mRawShadowSize;

    private boolean mDirty = true;

    private final int mShadowStartColor;

    private final int mShadowEndColor;

    private boolean mAddPaddingForCorners = true;

    /**
     * If shadow size is set to a value above max shadow, we print a warning
     */
    private boolean mPrintedShadowClipWarning = false;

    public RoundRectDrawableWithShadow(
            Resources resources, int backgroundColor, float radius,
            float shadowSize, float maxShadowSize
    ) {
        mShadowStartColor = resources.getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_start_color);
        mShadowEndColor = resources.getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_end_color);
        mInsetShadow = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cardview_compat_inset_shadow);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        mCornerShadowPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mCornerRadius = (int) (radius + .5f);
        mCardBounds = new RectF();
        mEdgeShadowPaint = new Paint(mCornerShadowPaint);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        setShadowSize(shadowSize, maxShadowSize);

        RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.sRoundRectHelper
                = new RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.RoundRectHelper() {
            @Override
            public void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, RectF bounds, float cornerRadius,
                    Paint paint) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Casts the value to an even integer.
     */
    private int toEven(float value) {
        int i = (int) (value + .5f);
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            return i - 1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void setAddPaddingForCorners(boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        mAddPaddingForCorners = addPaddingForCorners;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mDirty = true;
    }

    void setShadowSize(float shadowSize, float maxShadowSize) {
        if (shadowSize < 0 || maxShadowSize < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid shadow size");
        }
        shadowSize = toEven(shadowSize);
        maxShadowSize = toEven(maxShadowSize);
        if (shadowSize > maxShadowSize) {
            shadowSize = maxShadowSize;
            if (!mPrintedShadowClipWarning) {
                mPrintedShadowClipWarning = true;
            }
        }
        if (mRawShadowSize == shadowSize && mRawMaxShadowSize == maxShadowSize) {
            return;
        }
        mRawShadowSize = shadowSize;
        mRawMaxShadowSize = maxShadowSize;
        mShadowSize = (int)(shadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + mInsetShadow + .5f);
        mMaxShadowSize = maxShadowSize + mInsetShadow;
        mDirty = true;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getPadding(Rect padding) {
        int vOffset = (int) Math.ceil(calculateVerticalPadding(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius,
                mAddPaddingForCorners));
//        int hOffset = (int) Math.ceil(calculateHorizontalPadding(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius,
//                mAddPaddingForCorners));
//        padding.set(hOffset, vOffset, hOffset, vOffset);
        padding.set(0, vOffset, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }

    static float calculateVerticalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius,
            boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        if (addPaddingForCorners) {
            return (float) (maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
        } else {
            return maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER;
        }
    }

    static float calculateHorizontalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius,
            boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        if (addPaddingForCorners) {
            return (float) (maxShadowSize + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
        } else {
            return maxShadowSize;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    void setCornerRadius(float radius) {
        radius = (int) (radius + .5f);
        if (mCornerRadius == radius) {
            return;
        }
        mCornerRadius = radius;
        mDirty = true;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDirty) {
            buildComponents(getBounds());
            mDirty = false;
        }
        canvas.translate(0, -mRawShadowSize / 2);
        drawShadow(canvas);
        canvas.translate(0, +mRawShadowSize / 2);
        sRoundRectHelper.drawRoundRect(canvas, mCardBounds, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
    }

    private void drawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        final float edgeShadowTop = -mCornerRadius - mShadowSize;
        final float insetVertical = mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow + mRawShadowSize / 2;
        final float insetHorizontal = -mInsetShadow;
        // LT top
        int saved = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mCardBounds.left + insetHorizontal, mCardBounds.top + insetVertical);
        canvas.drawPath(mCornerShadowPath, mCornerShadowPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, edgeShadowTop,
                mCardBounds.width() - 2 * insetHorizontal, -mCornerRadius + mShadowSize,
                mEdgeShadowPaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saved);

        // RT right
        saved = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mCardBounds.right - insetHorizontal, mCardBounds.top + insetVertical);
        canvas.rotate(90f);
        canvas.drawPath(mCornerShadowPath, mCornerShadowPaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saved);
    }

    private void buildShadowCorners() {
        RectF innerBounds = new RectF(-mCornerRadius, -mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius);
        RectF outerBounds = new RectF(innerBounds);
        outerBounds.inset(-mShadowSize, -mShadowSize);

        if (mCornerShadowPath == null) {
            mCornerShadowPath = new Path();
        } else {
            mCornerShadowPath.reset();
        }
        mCornerShadowPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        mCornerShadowPath.moveTo(-mCornerRadius, 0);
        mCornerShadowPath.rLineTo(-mShadowSize, 0);
        // outer arc
        mCornerShadowPath.arcTo(outerBounds, 180f, 90f, false);
        // inner arc
        mCornerShadowPath.arcTo(innerBounds, 270f, -90f, false);
        mCornerShadowPath.close();
        float startRatio = mCornerRadius / (mCornerRadius + mShadowSize);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0, 0, mCornerRadius + mShadowSize,
                new int[]{mShadowStartColor, mShadowStartColor, mShadowEndColor},
                new float[]{0f, startRatio, 1f}
                , Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        // we offset the content shadowSize/2 pixels up to make it more realistic.
        // this is why edge shadow shader has some extra space
        // When drawing bottom edge shadow, we use that extra space.
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, -mCornerRadius + mShadowSize, 0,
                -mCornerRadius - mShadowSize,
                new int[]{mShadowStartColor, mShadowStartColor, mShadowEndColor},
                new float[]{0f, .5f, 1f}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    }

    private void buildComponents(Rect bounds) {
        // Card is offset SHADOW_MULTIPLIER * maxShadowSize to account for the shadow shift.
        // We could have different top-bottom offsets to avoid extra gap above but in that case
        // center aligning Views inside the CardView would be problematic.
        final float verticalOffset = mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER;
        mCardBounds.set(bounds.left + mRawMaxShadowSize, bounds.top + verticalOffset,
                bounds.right - mRawMaxShadowSize, bounds.bottom - verticalOffset);
        buildShadowCorners();
    }

    float getCornerRadius() {
        return mCornerRadius;
    }

    void getMaxShadowAndCornerPadding(Rect into) {
        getPadding(into);
    }

    void setShadowSize(float size) {
        setShadowSize(size, mRawMaxShadowSize);
    }

    void setMaxShadowSize(float size) {
        setShadowSize(mRawShadowSize, size);
    }

    float getShadowSize() {
        return mRawShadowSize;
    }

    float getMaxShadowSize() {
        return mRawMaxShadowSize;
    }

    float getMinWidth() {
        final float content = 2 *
                Math.max(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow + mRawMaxShadowSize / 2);
        return content + (mRawMaxShadowSize + mInsetShadow) * 2;
    }

    float getMinHeight() {
        final float content = 2 * Math.max(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow
                        + mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER / 2);
        return content + (mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + mInsetShadow) * 2;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    static interface RoundRectHelper {
        void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, RectF bounds, float cornerRadius, Paint paint);
    }
}
```

Work like a charm for me.

Comment: The shadow is cast upwards, but there is a white background behind it which should be transparent....

Comment: Can you post your full layout xml?

Comment: I posted my [full question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577720/how-to-create-a-top-shadow-using-modified-android-cardview-project-code). Thanks.

Comment: What value did you use for density?

Comment: Regarding the density, it is device specific: float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;