# How to y-offset the Android 5 Lollipop shadow direction

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, shadow

I used the android material design library to make a tab strip like this.

[image]

I added a view at the bottom of the screen like so.

[image]

Right now, I am trying to add the shadow effect from the top widget to the bottom view.

I found a solution in the form of an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582972/android-5-lollipop-shadow-direction-or-y-offset/28198388#comment54856373_28198388).

> The only way I found to create a top shadow was to modify some of the source of the Android compatibility v7 CardView project. This project brings the CardView class to older Android versions and thus also includes the elevation shadow. The resulting shadow is very close to a "real" elevation shadow.

I followed the instructions, and I ended with the following result to use an illustration

[image]

I added these colors to `res/values/values.xml`

```
<color name="cardview_shadow_end_color">#03000000</color>
<color name="cardview_shadow_start_color">#47000000</color>
<dimen name="cardview_compat_inset_shadow">1dp</dimen>
```

And I used the class `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow` from the modified Android compatibility v7 CardView project to set the shadow

```
float elevation = 200;
float density = 0.1f;
View bottomView = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottomView);
    bottomView.setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundRectDrawableWithShadow(
    getResources(), Color.BLACK, 0,
    elevation * density, ((elevation + 1) * density) + 1
));
```

Here is my modifed CardView project code `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow` class

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


/**
 * A rounded rectangle drawable which also includes a shadow around.
 */
public class RoundRectDrawableWithShadow extends Drawable {
    // used to calculate content padding
    final static double COS_45 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45));

    final static float SHADOW_MULTIPLIER = 1.5f;

    final int mInsetShadow; // extra shadow to avoid gaps between card and shadow

    /*
    * This helper is set by CardView implementations.
    * <p>
    * Prior to API 17, canvas.drawRoundRect is expensive; which is why we need this interface
    * to draw efficient rounded rectangles before 17.
    * */
    static RoundRectHelper sRoundRectHelper;

    Paint mPaint;

    Paint mCornerShadowPaint;

    Paint mEdgeShadowPaint;

    final RectF mCardBounds;

    float mCornerRadius;

    Path mCornerShadowPath;

    // updated value with inset
    float mMaxShadowSize;

    // actual value set by developer
    float mRawMaxShadowSize;

    // multiplied value to account for shadow offset
    float mShadowSize;

    // actual value set by developer
    float mRawShadowSize;

    private boolean mDirty = true;

    private final int mShadowStartColor;

    private final int mShadowEndColor;

    private boolean mAddPaddingForCorners = true;

    /**
     * If shadow size is set to a value above max shadow, we print a warning
     */
    private boolean mPrintedShadowClipWarning = false;

    public RoundRectDrawableWithShadow(
            Resources resources, int backgroundColor, float radius,
            float shadowSize, float maxShadowSize
    ) {
        mShadowStartColor = resources.getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_start_color);
        mShadowEndColor = resources.getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_end_color);
        mInsetShadow = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cardview_compat_inset_shadow);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        mCornerShadowPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mCornerRadius = (int) (radius + .5f);
        mCardBounds = new RectF();
        mEdgeShadowPaint = new Paint(mCornerShadowPaint);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        setShadowSize(shadowSize, maxShadowSize);

        RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.sRoundRectHelper
                = new RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.RoundRectHelper() {
            @Override
            public void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, RectF bounds, float cornerRadius,
                                      Paint paint) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Casts the value to an even integer.
     */
    private int toEven(float value) {
        int i = (int) (value + .5f);
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            return i - 1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void setAddPaddingForCorners(boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        mAddPaddingForCorners = addPaddingForCorners;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mDirty = true;
    }

    void setShadowSize(float shadowSize, float maxShadowSize) {
        if (shadowSize < 0 || maxShadowSize < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid shadow size");
        }
        shadowSize = toEven(shadowSize);
        maxShadowSize = toEven(maxShadowSize);
        if (shadowSize > maxShadowSize) {
            shadowSize = maxShadowSize;
            if (!mPrintedShadowClipWarning) {
                mPrintedShadowClipWarning = true;
            }
        }
        if (mRawShadowSize == shadowSize && mRawMaxShadowSize == maxShadowSize) {
            return;
        }
        mRawShadowSize = shadowSize;
        mRawMaxShadowSize = maxShadowSize;
        mShadowSize = (int)(shadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + mInsetShadow + .5f);
        mMaxShadowSize = maxShadowSize + mInsetShadow;
        mDirty = true;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getPadding(Rect padding) {
        int vOffset = (int) Math.ceil(calculateVerticalPadding(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius,
                mAddPaddingForCorners));
//        int hOffset = (int) Math.ceil(calculateHorizontalPadding(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius,
//                mAddPaddingForCorners));
//        padding.set(hOffset, vOffset, hOffset, vOffset);
        padding.set(0, vOffset, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }

    static float calculateVerticalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius,
                                          boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        if (addPaddingForCorners) {
            return (float) (maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
        } else {
            return maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER;
        }
    }

    static float calculateHorizontalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius,
                                            boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
        if (addPaddingForCorners) {
            return (float) (maxShadowSize + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
        } else {
            return maxShadowSize;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    void setCornerRadius(float radius) {
        radius = (int) (radius + .5f);
        if (mCornerRadius == radius) {
            return;
        }
        mCornerRadius = radius;
        mDirty = true;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDirty) {
            buildComponents(getBounds());
            mDirty = false;
        }
        canvas.translate(0, -mRawShadowSize / 2);
        drawShadow(canvas);
        canvas.translate(0, +mRawShadowSize / 2);
        sRoundRectHelper.drawRoundRect(canvas, mCardBounds, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
    }

    private void drawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        final float edgeShadowTop = -mCornerRadius - mShadowSize;
        final float insetVertical = mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow + mRawShadowSize / 2;
        final float insetHorizontal = -mInsetShadow;
        // LT top
        int saved = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mCardBounds.left + insetHorizontal, mCardBounds.top + insetVertical);
        canvas.drawPath(mCornerShadowPath, mCornerShadowPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, edgeShadowTop,
                mCardBounds.width() - 2 * insetHorizontal, -mCornerRadius + mShadowSize,
                mEdgeShadowPaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saved);

        // RT right
        saved = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mCardBounds.right - insetHorizontal, mCardBounds.top + insetVertical);
        canvas.rotate(90f);
        canvas.drawPath(mCornerShadowPath, mCornerShadowPaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saved);
    }

    private void buildShadowCorners() {
        RectF innerBounds = new RectF(-mCornerRadius, -mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius);
        RectF outerBounds = new RectF(innerBounds);
        outerBounds.inset(-mShadowSize, -mShadowSize);

        if (mCornerShadowPath == null) {
            mCornerShadowPath = new Path();
        } else {
            mCornerShadowPath.reset();
        }
        mCornerShadowPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        mCornerShadowPath.moveTo(-mCornerRadius, 0);
        mCornerShadowPath.rLineTo(-mShadowSize, 0);
        // outer arc
        mCornerShadowPath.arcTo(outerBounds, 180f, 90f, false);
        // inner arc
        mCornerShadowPath.arcTo(innerBounds, 270f, -90f, false);
        mCornerShadowPath.close();
        float startRatio = mCornerRadius / (mCornerRadius + mShadowSize);
        mCornerShadowPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0, 0, mCornerRadius + mShadowSize,
                new int[]{mShadowStartColor, mShadowStartColor, mShadowEndColor},
                new float[]{0f, startRatio, 1f}
                , Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        // we offset the content shadowSize/2 pixels up to make it more realistic.
        // this is why edge shadow shader has some extra space
        // When drawing bottom edge shadow, we use that extra space.
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, -mCornerRadius + mShadowSize, 0,
                -mCornerRadius - mShadowSize,
                new int[]{mShadowStartColor, mShadowStartColor, mShadowEndColor},
                new float[]{0f, .5f, 1f}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        mEdgeShadowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    }

    private void buildComponents(Rect bounds) {
        // Card is offset SHADOW_MULTIPLIER * maxShadowSize to account for the shadow shift.
        // We could have different top-bottom offsets to avoid extra gap above but in that case
        // center aligning Views inside the CardView would be problematic.
        final float verticalOffset = mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER;
        mCardBounds.set(bounds.left + mRawMaxShadowSize, bounds.top + verticalOffset,
                bounds.right - mRawMaxShadowSize, bounds.bottom - verticalOffset);
        buildShadowCorners();
    }

    float getCornerRadius() {
        return mCornerRadius;
    }

    void getMaxShadowAndCornerPadding(Rect into) {
        getPadding(into);
    }

    void setShadowSize(float size) {
        setShadowSize(size, mRawMaxShadowSize);
    }

    void setMaxShadowSize(float size) {
        setShadowSize(mRawShadowSize, size);
    }

    float getShadowSize() {
        return mRawShadowSize;
    }

    float getMaxShadowSize() {
        return mRawMaxShadowSize;
    }

    float getMinWidth() {
        final float content = 2 *
                Math.max(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow + mRawMaxShadowSize / 2);
        return content + (mRawMaxShadowSize + mInsetShadow) * 2;
    }

    float getMinHeight() {
        final float content = 2 * Math.max(mRawMaxShadowSize, mCornerRadius + mInsetShadow
                + mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER / 2);
        return content + (mRawMaxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + mInsetShadow) * 2;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    static interface RoundRectHelper {
        void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, RectF bounds, float cornerRadius, Paint paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was drawing a rectangle ove the entire view. The rectangle needs to be drawn on a seperate view dedicated to the shadow effect.

Additionally, the shadow view should have a height no greater than 6dp, or the rectangle will show, if that makes sense.

One last note, use these values for density and elevation

```
float elevation = 2;
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This Is A Fragment"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/other"/>

    <View
        android:id="@id/other"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The density is device dependent, you should use this: float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Comment: Maybe it's just an impression, but the shadow looks a little darker than the tab strip shadow.